# Euler's Derivation of Sum of Inverse Squares?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, taylor-expansion

So one of my absolute favorite arguments in mathematics I have ever seen in Euler's initial argument for the following;

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^2} = \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$$

His argument (note that I do not say proof) proceeds as follows;

By Taylor expansions, we can write

$$\dfrac{\sin{x}}{x} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!} $$

Note also that, for finite polynomials, we can factor over the roots. Since this is a "polynomial", it is not unreasonable to factor it over its roots (this is the step I am going to ask about). The zeroes of $\sin{x}/x$ are the nonzero integer multiples of $\pi$, so we can write

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!} = (\dfrac{x}{\pi} - 1)(\dfrac{x}{\pi} + 1)(\dfrac{x}{2\pi}-1)(\dfrac{x}{2\pi}+1)\dots = (\dfrac{x^2}{\pi^2} - 1)(\dfrac{x^2}{4\pi^2}-1)\dots$$

Collecting the $x^2$ terms on each side, we obtain

$$ \dfrac{-x^2}{6} = - x^2 (\dfrac{1}{\pi^2} + \dfrac{1}{4\pi^2} + \dots) = -x^2 \dfrac{1}{\pi^2} \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^2}$$

Which, when simplified, yields the correct result. I absolutely love this argument, I think the ingenuity to factor a Taylor polynomial is something only Euler would have thought to do. However, I recognize that at least at the time he did this, that was not a rigorous mathematical proof, as the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra applies to finite polynomials (so far as I am aware). Has this method been proven to be rigorous since Euler's time? Are there restrictions on what kinds of infinite polynomials can be factored?

Comment: On Euler times this was not rigorous. It was proved as correct some time after. Any convergent power series can be factorized in it radius of convergence. Indeed we can factorize too formal power series because formal power series are not functions on the $x$.

Comment: See http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/311/cotan.pdf which is more or less the elementary rigorous proof that [Euler found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#History_of_this_proof) after a few years of work. Otherwise the [modern and general way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem) : show that $g(z)=\frac{z}{\sin(z)}\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-\frac{z^2}{\pi^2 n^2})$ is an entire function with no zeros, and that $\log g(z)$ is entire and bounded, so it has to be constant by the Liouville theorem.

Comment: It becomes a rigorous argument after the Mittag-Leffler and Weierstrass factorization theorems.